# AJAX Forms with JQuery - Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined

Tags: jquery, ajax

I´ve found this great tutorial for creating a simple form with ajax: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/submitting-ajax-forms-with-jquery

But the error is: `Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined`
I would like to use this ajax form for sending a mail, but it´s not really working.
It seems that the php script (have a look at the link) doesn´t send back the json data string or the form.js cannot read it? I don´t know and I am really stuck in this example.
Has anyone a hint, what could be wrong with this example?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("form").submit(function (event) {
    var formData = {
      name: $("#name").val(),
      email: $("#email").val(),
      superheroAlias: $("#superheroAlias").val(),
    };
   
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "process.php",
      data: formData,
      dataType: "json",
      encode: true,
    }).done(function (data) {
      console.log(data);

      if (!data.success) {
        if (data.errors.name) {
          $("#name-group").addClass("has-error");
          $("#name-group").append(
            '<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.name + "</div>"
          );
        }

        if (data.errors.email) {
          $("#email-group").addClass("has-error");
          $("#email-group").append(
            '<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.email + "</div>"
          );
        }

        if (data.errors.superheroAlias) {
          $("#superhero-group").addClass("has-error");
          $("#superhero-group").append(
            '<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.superheroAlias + "</div>"
          );
        }
      } else {
        $("form").html(
          '<div class="alert alert-success">' + data.message + "</div>"
        );
      }

    });

    event.preventDefault();
  });
// ...
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>jQuery Form Example</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="form.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
      <h1>Processing an AJAX Form</h1>

      <form action="process.php" method="POST">
        <div id="name-group" class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Name</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="name"
            name="name"
            placeholder="Full Name"
          />
        </div>

        <div id="email-group" class="form-group">
          <label for="email">Email</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="email"
            name="email"
            placeholder="email@example.com"
          />
        </div>

        <div id="superhero-group" class="form-group">
          <label for="superheroAlias">Superhero Alias</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="superheroAlias"
            name="superheroAlias"
            placeholder="Ant Man, Wonder Woman, Black Panther, Superman, Black Widow"
          />
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you see in your console when you do the `console.log(data);`? Which line is actually throwing the error?

Comment: Start debugging. Check your browser's devtools, inspect the network requests - is the right data sent with your POST? How does the server respond? Have you checked your web server/PHP logs?  PS: pls don't refer to code off-site - reproduce the *minimial* necessary code here.  Please see how to creaet a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).